# Server finished by itself python

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I'm working with python and trying to build simple server and client, that the client sends data (massage one after one) and the server replies to the massages (yet with the word "hello")

The problem is that when I try to run the server it automatically finished by itself...

server code:

```
import socket
IP_ADDRESS, PORT = "127.0.0.1", 3016

def main():
    connect()

def connect():
    server_socket = socket.socket()
    server_socket.bind((IP_ADDRESS, PORT))
    server_socket.listen(1)
    while True:
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        client_socket.send("Welcome!")
        request = ""
        try:
            while request != "EXIT":
                request = client_socket.recv(1024)
                client_socket.send("hello")
        except Exception, e:
            client_socket.send("Error:" + e.message)
        client_socket.close()
    server_socket.close()
main()
```

client code:

```
import socket
IP_ADDRESS, PORT = "127.0.0.1", 3016

def main():
    client_socket = socket.socket() # creating tcp socket
    client_socket.connect((IP_ADDRESS, PORT))
    print client_socket.recv(1024) # welcome massage
    request = ""
    while True:
        request = raw_input("Enter request: ")
        client_socket.send(request)
        answer = client_socket.recv(1024)
        print answer
        if "Error" in answer:
            break
    client_socket.close()
main()
```

Comment: Where do you call `main` in your server and client code?

Comment: Oops. In my code there is main but I have forgotten to add it here. However, the server finished after one massage (finished by itself) :(

Comment: I cannot duplicate your problem.

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine

Comment: Although the code works (as in the server does Not finish after one message (one message what ? )), did you intend to put that `server_socket.close()` in the server code there? Because that line of code will never be reached.